# why must I frequently rebuild the icon cache in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons

Every few days of usage this will randomly occur on my windows 7 pro 64-bit pc:

1. All explorer entries in the task bar will revert to the generic non-icon.
2. If I try to run anything from start->run, such as cmd, environment variables get cleared. Other apps will act nutty when launched sometimes as well.

This is the fix that I have to perform to get things working again. I have to run the batch directly form explorer, since running from start->run will fail because of the mentioned variable issue:

```
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
attrib -h iconcache.db
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
del iconcache.db
start %windir%\explorer.exe
```

Why does this keep happening? I run many apps at once but I have 16 gigs of ram.

Comment: How often are you running Windows Updates and do you have Itunes installed?

Comment: Also, when the icons are not working as desired, does the application still run when clicked or do you lose association as well?

Comment: No itunes. Windows updates semi-frequent and are handled by company deployment. The taskbar icons still resolve to explorer.